# Why is rvalue references considered safer than lvalue references?

Tags: c++

Before C++11 it was only const lvalue references that could bind to rvalues since rvalue references did not exist and non-const lvalue references could not bind to rvalues. The reason, afaik, why non-const lvalue references could not bind to rvalues was that it would be dangerous. So then they made rvalue references which made it possible to move data... but why is rvalue references bound to rvalues considered safer than non-const lvalue references bound to rvalues?

Comment: Are you talking about the reasoning for `std::move()`?

Comment: Just like a const lvalue reference, rvalue references extend the lifetime of their referent.  Non-const lvalue references do not exhibit this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of rvalue references over lvalue references is that with rvalue references you *know* that the object referred to is an rvalue. Thus you know that you are allowed to manipulate it without damaging other data.

If non-const lvalue references were allowed to refer to rvalues, you would never know if the object referred to was temporary or not. Consider, for example these two constructors

```
class A {
public:
    A(A& src) // Copy constructor
    {
       // Create a copy of src, but be sure to leave src intact
    }

    A(A&& src) // Move constructor
    {
        // Create a copy of src. If necessary, you can steal some
        // of src's resources (dynamic memory, open files). It
        // won't miss it
    }
};
```

The performance advantage you can get in the second version cannot be achieved in the first, even if lvalue references were allowed to refer to rvalues.

Comment: Ahh so it is all because of "safety"? In fact, they could add the same functionality to non-const lvalue reference as for rvalue references, but they forbade this usage of non-const lvalue reference because it would be too unsafe? If so, couldn't they just stay allow non-const lvalue references to be bound to rvalues and let users be responsible for using it correctly? Then they would not even have to make another reference type(rvalue references)?

Comment: It's not a matter of using it correctly. By allowing rvalue references to do some otherwise destructive manipulation of the object referred to, a performance advantage can sometimes be achieved. I'll edit my reply to reflect this.

Comment: Hmmm well.. But couldn't the same be achieved by non-const lvalue references, like the moving part?

Comment: No. I've updated my answer. You need some way to be able to distinguish between a `src` that is an lvalue and a `src` that is an rvalue.

Comment: Yeah okay now it makes more sense to me. However, other than being able to distinguish between rvalues and lvalues, there is not really anything that a non-const lvalue reference(if allowed to bind to rvalues) could not do that rvalue references could do, correct? If so, is the distinguish part **the** reason why rvalues references were created?

Comment: I believe that is the case.